# Use 3rd party CSS with Ionic

Tags: css, angular, ionic3

I am currently porting one of my Cordova+Angular2 projects to Ionic 3.8+Angular 4.1.3. My project uses a few 3rd part JS and CSS libraries like Font awesome, Slick carousel etc. In the previous version, I used webpack for packaging my app and below is how I managed 3rd party css and JS.

.angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "css/animate.css",
    "css/font-awesome.css",
    "css/slick.css",
    "css/slick-theme.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [
    "scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js",
    "scripts/slick.min.js",
    "scripts/slideout.min.js"
  ],
```

How do I achieve the same with Ionic? I have gone through the solutions available online, but most of them recommend combining the css to the global scss file, or even tweaking ionic. Is there a straightforward solution for this as with angular cli?

Comment: In my case, i add direct link in to index.html

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic 3 this is actually pretty tricky, we'll have to dig a bit into Ionic App Scripts. The easier way is to add a link to your `index.html` as Duannx points out in the comments.

The good news is: In Ionic v4 there will be no Ionic App Scripts anymore and you'll be able to manage your custom CSS as pointed out above using an `angular.json` file. See the official v4 announcement [here](https://blog.ionicframework.com/announcing-ionic-4-beta/).

---

If we want to do it *the right way* in Ionic v3 we'll have to do the following after installing our custom CSS solution via npm e.g.:

```
npm install slick-carousel
```

**1. Copy and edit the `sass.config.js` from Ionic App Scripts**

Go to `node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/config` and copy the `sass.config.js` file. I copied it to my project's root directory. Then edit the file: Add paths to your custom CSS to the `includePaths` section, e.g. I added the path to the slick-carousel node_module:

```
includePaths: [
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/themes',
    'node_modules/ionicons/dist/scss',
    'node_modules/ionic-angular/fonts',
    'node_modules/slick-carousel/slick'
  ],
```

**2. Link our new `sass.config.js` in `package.json`**

Now let's link our new SASS configuration in our `package.json`. This is [well documented in the App Scripts readme](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration). Add a config section with following content:

```
"config": {
    "ionic_sass": "./sass.config.js"
  }
```

As pointed out before my new `sass.config.js` is in my projects root directory. If you copied it elsewhere make sure to adjust the path accordingly.

**3. Import custom css files using `@import`**

Now we can finally import our custom CSS using [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import). A good place to do this is `variables.scss`.

Sad thing is: For slick-carousel we're not done yet. We'll also have to copy some fonts. But this shouldn't be to hard, we can do the same as above with `copy.config.js` and editing the `copyFonts` section.